# returning a method reference wrapped in a lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, reference, lambda

Please help me understand WHY the following works.

```
class Dog
  def bark
    "woof"
  end
end

bark_string = Dog.new.bark
puts bark_string                   # "woof" - a string at this point
ref_to_bark = -> { bark_string }   # the string a moment ago is now the method again
ref_to_bark.call                   # "woof"
```

**Why does wrapping a reference to a method in a proc/lambda return a reference to the original method?** It baffles me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas (and blocks, and procs) in Ruby are [*closures*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29); this means that local variables available in the same scope as the lambda is defined are accessible *inside* the lambda. For example:

```
foo = 42
l = lambda{ p foo }
l.call()
#=> 42
```

The above should not be any more surprising than the fact that this code works:

```
x = 17
[1,2,3].map do |n|
  n+x # Whoa, you can use _x_ here?!
end
#=> [18,19,20]
```

It's slightly more surprising when you do something like this:

```
def make_adder( x )
  ->(y){ x+y }
end
add10 = make_adder(10)
z = add10.call(32)     #=> 42
```

Again, the local variable *x* (the parameter passed to the method) is "closed over" by the lambda, its value preserved for reference whenever the lambda is invoked.

So in your example **the lambda is just "capturing" the `bark_string` variable** and returning its value later on. Your method is never invoked a second time.

---

Note that a closure captures the variable itself, not just the object referred to by the variable:

```
x = "hello"
y = x         # reference the same _object_
l = ->{ x }   # close over the _variable_ itself
x = "world"   # change the variable to point to a new object

p y,          #=> "hello"     (same object as the original)
  l[]         #=> "world"     (new object)
```

Comment: wow, this is the type of clear and thorough explanation i was looking for. thank you

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't. `ref_to_bark` just returns `bark_string`, the `bark` method is not called.

Comment: I don't see how you can say it's returning `bark_string`. Because `bark_string` is the string "woof". When it's wrapped with `-> { bark_string }` it becomes the method again. THAT is the part that is very strange to me.

Comment: It's like `ref_to_bark = -> { "woof" }`, it becomes a method, but not _that_ method.

Comment: To prove to yourself that the method isn't getting called again, try defining a method like `def test; Time.now; end`. You'll see that when you wrap it in a lambda and call that lambda, you still get the same timestamp as the first time you ran the method no matter how long you wait.

Comment: So it's just storing the return value from the method? That's it?? So simple.

Comment: @Brand FYI, this would return an actual reference: `ref_to_bark = Dog.new.method(:bark)`

Answer (score 0):

A lambda defined using -> is called lambda literal. Sometimes called stabby lambda. The following will also return the same result.

```
ref_to_bark = lambda { bark_string }
```

Or

```
ref_to_bark = lambda { "woof" }
```